# Looking for a post apocalyptic movie from 70's about survivors in a nuclear bunker

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

I've been looking for a post apocalyptic nuclear war survival movie. I only remember a few bits and pieces, and hoping someone might be able to identify it. I believe it's set in Europe. Perhaps in Germany. Can't remember. Here's what I remember.

1. Initially starts with 3-4 couples in a bunker
2. As time elapses the survivors begin to start degrading mentally and ethically. One of the male leads starts becoming tyrannical and ordering the others around, a couple others commit suicide.
3. Towards the end as they begin running out of food, one guy kills a girl and starts cannibalizing her legs.
4. To pass the time they play cards and use the game to gamble things like food, sex and more.
5. At the end only two make it out alive. When they venture outside they come across scores of people who died at home, in their beds or just out in the open. Making the future for these few very bleak.

Comment: Sounds like the start of [Damnation Alley](http://www.threemoviebuffs.com/review/damnation-alley.html). The rest doesn't match though

Comment: [The Bed Sitting Room](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=de0w8tU0j1U) meets a lot of these tropes

Answer (score 4):

"Refuge of Fear"(1974)?
A.k.a. "Creation of the Damned".

It's set in the U.S., I believe in California, but it is actually a Spanish film. I haven't actually seen it, it's very rare, but Sinister Cinema has a DVD-R of it that I plan to buy. The movie has a plot like you describe, two couples in a bomb shelter, and the mental breakdown of the characters. I don't know about the leg eating but there is a cat that gets eaten. There is also a notorious scene where the husband yells at the wife for parading herself around the bunker wearing almost nothing, so she comes to the dinner table wearing a decontamination suit! The IMDb page is posted below, just click on the link.

Creation of the Damned
http://imdb.com/rg/an_share/title/title/tt0072071/

Here is a review of the film from a web site called 'Bloody Pit of Horror', under it's Spanish title "El Refugio Del Miedo".

http://thebloodypitofhorror.blogspot.com/2012/02/refugio-del-miedo-el-1973.html